# Remove Alt Required validation from image

Tags: validation

I need to remove `Alt required` validation from Alt field in Image template, I removed `Alt required` validation from template image in path `/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Unversioned/Image`

[image]

But when i create field in template from type image and select uploaded image without Alt text, validation is shown.[image]

is there way to remove this validation?

Comment: Answer below is good. Also just a suggestion - it is not best practice to modify base Sitecore templates. A future update could possibly break your solution. Best Regards!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to `/sitecore/system/Settings/Validation Rules/Field Types/Image` item and remove the `Image Has Alt Text` from the `Validation Rules` section where you don't want to run this validator. What you removed is the validator on the Image items in the media library.